# looking for a way to make woocommerce products custom attributes values searchable in front end search bar

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I am currently building a woocommerce website for computer products and I have a problem where several attribute fields need to be custom due to the limitations of woocommerece not allowing for free text values for global attributes. Because the attributes need to be custom they are not searchable by default and as such I need somehow make it possible to be searched by the search bar and as well as to be filtered on storefront.

I will add that I'am not a programmer but have some knowledge about programming just not in PHP

I have asked ChatGPT about the search option without the filter option, but every piece of code from it doesn't seem to work but I'll add the code just incase

```php
function custom_search_filter($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'product');
        $query->set('meta_query', array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'local_attribute_name_1', // Replace with the actual attribute name
                'value' => $query->query_vars['s'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'local_attribute_name_2', // Replace with the actual attribute name
                'value' => $query->query_vars['s'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            // Add more local attributes as needed
        ));
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'custom_search_filter');
```